# Update to the latest version of the iOS SDK

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

I am using xcode(5.0) and my device is having 7.1.1 (11D201)

my device is not appearing in xcode

in organizer i am getting as below

The version of iOS on “Device_name” is not supported by this installation of the iOS SDK. Please restore the device to a version of the OS listed below, or update to the latest version of the iOS SDK.

thanks in advnace

Comment: XCode 5.0 is not the latest version of XCode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The current version of your Xcode doesn't support iOS version >7.0. You need to upgrade your Xcode. You can get a latest version from Mac App Store.

Comment: Also (with the understanding that the OP is NOT on the latest XCode), it would still be good to remind the OP that Apple does not always update the simulator to 
"dot.dot" releases (ie: 7.1.1 still uses 7.1 simulator). "dot.dot" releases are generally user-releases for security bugs that would not -- in everyday life -- affect the build of your app or the way it uses the SDK.

Answer (score 0):

You need to open the Mac App Store or the Devloper Portal and download the latest version of Xcode / iOS SDK.

Answer (score -2):

You do need latest xcode 5.1, however, once you open your project in xcode 5.1 and select device you want to use. You can then go back to xcode 5.0 and it will work there as well.

Comment: The latest version of XCode is not 5.1

Comment: this is wrong, new xcodes have latest sdks embedded with them and the OP needs those